# Is Unix md5sum command correct way to compare content of two files

Tags: unix

I have two files (e.g. `File1` and `File2`) and i'd like to compare them to be sure that their contents are completely identical. Is `md5sum` `Unix` command appropriate way to do it?

For instance, having :

```
md5sum File1
99596524e0642ad4b7fd5b3d5c472d77

md5sum File2
99596524e0642ad4b7fd5b3d5c472d77
```

Can i conclude that the content of both files is identical to each other?

Comment: The files are very likely to be same, but you can't be 100% sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cmp` is a standard command-line utility for comparing files.

If the files are identical, no output is printed and the process exit code is 0. If the files are different, the location of the difference is printed and the exit code is 1. An exit code of 2 means an error occurred.

If File1 and File2 are identical but File3 differs, you will see the following results:

```
$ cmp File1 File2
$ cmp File1 File3
File1 File3 differ: byte 1562, line 37
```

[GNU man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cmp.1.html)

GNU [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Invoking-cmp.html#Invoking-cmp) and [options](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/cmp-Options.html#cmp-Options)

[BSD man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/bsd/1/cmp/)